# Self-Registration Alert Administrator Email Template

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, email, email-template

I created a trigger to make new self reg users inActive after registering.
Then created a workflow to email the Admin when a user self registered and to verify and activate that user.

In my email template i am trying to link to the User who just self registered so the admin can directly go to that user record from the email. 
Is there a way to achieve this? I didn't see anyway to do this using merge fields.

Comment: Looks like if i use {!Target_user.Link} it doesn't show anything, but i am able to get other info like {!Target_user.CommunityNickname} that works.

Answer (score 2):

If the email alert of the workflow is related to a user, you can use something like `{!User.Link}` to create a link directly to the user. This should work with any type of record, as long as you have the record related to the email alert.

Comment: Thanks I tried that but that takes me to the Partner Portal Site Guest User record.

Comment: Can you post the email template, or at least a reduced version of it, in your question? It might help provide some insight on which fields, or which objects to use.

Comment: I don't have too much context yet. but here is what i want to do.

"
Hi <sales manager's name>,

New user has registered for communities. Please verify and activate the following user : {!newly registered User Here}.
"

Comment: What object are you trying to link too? Is it not the user?

Comment: It is the user but for some reason i pulls the "Partner portal guest user" record instead of the User that submitted registration form. 
I have a trigger that keeps that user inactive after registering and i want the sales manager to go and activate that user. Maybe it's not possible because that user is inactive.

Comment: Wouldnt this user who submitted the form be the portal user? Arent self registered users required to sign up from a portal?

Comment: Yes, the user is the portal user but once they sign up they get their own user record with the username they picked even though they are not active yet. That is what i am trying to get to.. but the Email template takes me to the "partner portal guest user" record which is a generic user for someone who has not registered yet.

Comment: Check what the workflow is targeting, you may need to adjust the target object. Id like to avoid filling this question with comments, so if you have another question, Id recommend posting it separately, if you dont get a better answer anytime soon.